# Python: Loading .txt files into different lists

Tags: python, list

Please excuse my silly question as I am really new to python.

I have 20 different .txt files (eg `"myfile_%s"` with `s` having been attributed to an integer in range=1,21). So I load them as follows:

```
runs=range(1,21)

for i in runs:

     Myfile=np.loadtxt("myfile_%s.txt" %i, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Hence, they're being loaded into a variable of "float64" type.
I would like to load them into 20 different lists (so as to find the maximum value of each etc.).

Thank you in advance!

PS: I would be happy to hear any textbook recommendations for python beginners.

Comment: Just load all of them into one big numpy array (line by line) and do the maximum value along the correct axis.

Comment: Try list comprehension, `matrices = [np.loadtxt("myfile_%s.txt" %i, delimiter=',', unpack=True) for i in range(1,21)]`. You can access each matrix (I presume each file results in a matrix) by its index. i.e. `mat2_max = np.max(matrices[1])` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can split using your delimiter and load into a native python list:

```
my_files = []

for i in range(1,21):
    with open("my_file_{0}.txt".format(i), 'r') as f:
        my_files.append(f.read().split(','))
```

Now you have a list of lists. You can get the max overall, or get the max of each list, like so:

```
# max of each
max_values = [max(map(float,my_list)) for my_list in my_files]

# max overall
max_overall = max(max_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your lists of equal length? If yes, you can do everything in one numpy array:

```
a = np.zeros((100,20))

for i in range(1,21):
  a[i-1,:]=np.loadtxt("myfile_%s.txt" %i, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Now you can do all `numpy` functions on the resulting array such as

```
b = np.sum(a,axis=0)
```